# Ember 'undefined is not a function' GET request to posts api

Tags: ember.js

On my quest to learn Ember, I'm trying to get Ember to make a GET request to /api/posts, and display a list of posts via handlebars.

Right now, it's successfuly making the get request, but chrome pops out these errors -

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at DS.JSONSerializer.DS.Serializer.extend.configureSideloadMappingForType (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:7798:10)
    at DS.JSONSerializer.DS.Serializer.extend.sideload (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:7768:10)
    at DS.JSONSerializer.DS.Serializer.extend.extractMany (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:7692:10)
    at superWrapper [as extractMany] (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:1293:16)
    at DS.Adapter.Ember.Object.extend.didFindAll (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:8307:16)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:9894:15
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:10014:19)
    at publish (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:9684:9)
    at publishFulfillment (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:10104:7)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:18381:7 ember.js?body=1:3522
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: TypeError: undefined is not a function ember.js?body=1:74
```

---

This is what my app looks like so far --

```
// http://emberjs.com/guides/models/using-the-store/
Blog.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: 'Blog.ApplicationAdapter'
});

Blog.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api'
})

// For more information see: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/
Blog.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts');
});

#posts.handlebars
<h1>Entries...</h1>
{{#each post in controller}}
  {{render "post" post}}
{{/each}}    

#post.handlebars
<h2>{{title}}</h2>

Blog.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('Post')
  }
})
Blog.Post = DS.Model.extend({});
```

How would I go about debugging this?

Comment: I haven't tested this but I noticed your Post model is empty.  Are you returning any data from the `/api/posts` REST endpoint?  Ember-data might be trying to process the data but fails since no model is defined.  You might want to try making sure the model matches the JSON you're returning and see if the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Blog.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('Post')
  }
})
```

I wrote:

```
Blog.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').find('post')
  }
})
```

Comment: I think you should be doing `this.store.find('post)`. ('post' is lowercase) This should return all posts.  I don't think `Blog.Post.find()` is the correct way to use the store. http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/

Comment: The `store` object is injected into the route so you should be able to access it just by using `this.store` instead of `this.get('store')`.  Glad it worked! You should accept your own answer so people know the question has an answer.